# Variável não está sendo decrementada conforme a linha excluída através do Dismissible

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um uma `ListView.builder` retornando uma `ListTile`, que adiciona o horário em `title` e valor "10" em `trailing` toda vez que o botão "ADD +10" é acionado.

Usei o widget `Dismissible` para fazer a exclusão dos itens, porém não consigo decrementar a variável `novoValor` quando uma linha é excluída através do `Dismissible`, já que a variável `novoValor` tem um valor e deveria ser decrementada em 10 toda vez que uma linha fosse excluída.

Já tentei diversas ações com o breve conhecimento que possuo em programação, mas não consegui nenhuma solução. Também fiz diversas pesquisas, mas não obtive êxito. Já se foram alguns dias tentando entender o que ocorre.

Só para esclarecimento, já tentei algumas alternativas, uma delas foi armazenar o valor da linha excluída em uma variável e assim usar para decrementar, não consegui nem recuperar o valor dessa linha excluída. Eu usei uma `List` com um `Map` dentro, então não consegui nem pegar o "value" da linha excluída do `Map`. Fase de aprendizagem rs.

Como a `key` e o `value` estão como `String`, eu tinha ciência que precisaria converter para `int`, mas sem sucesso.

Meu `onDismissed:` está sem linhas de código com alguma lógica para resolução do problema, mas é porque eu apaguei o que não estava funcionando.

Meu código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main (){
  runApp ( MaterialApp(
      home: Home()
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TimeOfDay horario;
  int valor = 10;
  int novoValor = 0;

  List lista = [];

  void addItens (){

    horario = TimeOfDay.now();

    Map <String, String> item = Map();
    item ['horario'] = '${horario.format(context)}';
    item ['valor'] = '$valor';
    lista.add (item);

    setState(() {
      novoValor += valor;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 150,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Color(0xff388df8), Color(0xff28c9fc)])
                    ),
                    child: Text('ADD +10',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors. white,
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap:addItens
              ),
            ),
            //Text colocado para testar se está incrementando e decrementando
            Text('Valor Atual: $novoValor'),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: lista.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
                    return Dismissible(
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      onDismissed: (direction){
                        lista.removeAt(indice);
                        setState(() {
                          novoValor -= lista.removeAt(indice);
                        });
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(lista[indice]['horario'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        trailing: Text(lista[indice]['valor'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é relacionado a sua lógica, vamos lá...

Aqui você está removendo o item da lista, depois você remove o item novamente com o `removeAt` que por sua vez retorna o item excluído que é um *Map* e não um integer...
Fazendo assim, você estaria removendo 2 itens seguidos.

```
onDismissed: (direction){
  lista.removeAt(indice);
  setState(() {
    novoValor -= lista.removeAt(indice);
  });
},
```

Basta você trocar esse bloco de código acima, pelo seguinte:

```
onDismissed: (direction){
  setState(() {
    novoValor -= int.parse(lista.removeAt(indice)["valor"]);
  });
},
```

Código completo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main (){
  runApp ( MaterialApp(
      home: Home()
  ));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TimeOfDay horario;
  int valor = 10;
  int novoValor = 0;

  List lista = [];

  void addItens (){

    horario = TimeOfDay.now();

    Map <String, String> item = Map();
    item ['horario'] = '${horario.format(context)}';
    item ['valor'] = '$valor';
    lista.add (item);

    setState(() {
      novoValor += valor;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 150,
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Color(0xff388df8), Color(0xff28c9fc)])
                    ),
                    child: Text('ADD +10',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors. white,
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap:addItens
              ),
            ),
            //Text colocado para testar se está incrementando e decrementando
            Text('Valor Atual: $novoValor'),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: lista.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
                    return Dismissible(
                      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      onDismissed: (direction){
                        setState(() {
                          novoValor -= int.parse(lista.removeAt(indice)["valor"]);
                        });
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(lista[indice]['horario'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        ),
                        trailing: Text(lista[indice]['valor'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Meu problema foi pelo fato de não saber extrair o poder que a programação pode me proporcionar. Até tenho o raciocínio e consegui fazer muitas coisas sozinho, porém as vezes acabo me limitando achando que as coisas devem ser feitas como uma receita de bolo.
Usei o ```removeAt``` conforme aprendi e simplesmente não imaginei que havia essa possibilidade que você fez.
As sintaxes escritas em ```Dismissible``` foram a última tentativa que eu tinha feito, antes foram feitas outras rs.
Agradeço mais uma vez e vou procurar algum material para melhorar.